# Cleditor. What is the way to remove instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a solution of this problem to the 1.4.4 version, but that code doesn't works with the last version of the editor.

```
//...

var lastChapter = textarea.cleditor({
     bodyStyle: "margin:4px; font:16px Arial,Verdana; cursor:text;",
     docCSSFile: "/css/cleditor.editor.css"
})[0];

lastChapter.$area.insertBefore(lastChapter[1].$main);
lastChapter.$area.removeData('cleditor');
lastChapter.$main.remove();
```

I'll be thankful!

Comment: I've solved problem and that's not in editor. That way still works excellent.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();
```

Comment: That's not a solution.